# Merging UIImageViews to save as 1 image - Transparent areas shows previous images

Tags: iphone, image-processing, uiimageview, transparency

My app lets users choose or take a picture then add other objects or text on top and rotate/resize them.

For saving i'm just taking a screenshot of the iPhone screen because after trying for hours and hours I just couldn't figure out how to save the original image with the added objects being placed at the right spots, with the right rotation/resized/etc... (If anyone knows a good example/tutorial of how to do this it would be incredibly helpful!)

I have a UIView with a size of 320x366. When user chooses an image I load it inside that UIView and it gets sized to fit properly with it's aspect ratio. When the user is done adding/editing objects on his image he can then save it.

```
-(UIImage *)createMergedImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(contentView.frame.size.width, contentView.frame.size.height), NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, contentView.frame.size.width,contentView.frame.size.height));
//contentView is the 320x366 view with all the images
    [contentView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenShot;
}
```

That's the code i'm using to save the UIView as a picture. Fitting the images with their correct shrunk aspect ratio, there's either transparent border at the top/bottom or left/right.

Now it's saving and works, when I open the image it's exactly what i'd expect. The problem is when i'm looking at the preview image, it shows other images (that i've previously seen on my iPhone) in the transparent part of the picture. As you can see in this following image.
[image: image 1]

When I go in the Camera Roll the transparent part looks black (like it should) as seen in this second image.
[image: image 2]

Also when i'm scrolling through my Camera Roll when I get to the image that my app saved, i'll see those extra random images in the transparent area for 0-1 secs before it disappears and becomes black (leaving the correct image the way it should be).

I'm hoping someone has seen something like this before and knows how to fix it.

Thanks!